# How to make a picaxe service remote for a pioneer ir controller for a DVR - 660H and DVP 540H DVD recorder

Tags: picaxe, infrared

How to make a picaxe service remote for a pioneer ir controller for a DVR - 660H and DVP 540H DVD recorder

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at the TV Be Gone project there are various schematics available (including one [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Double-the-Range-of-Your-TV-B-Gone/)) plus other information, maybe one of these might have some information you could use to help you.